# Calling functions from an array of pointers in a library causes 'undefined reference to' error

Tags: library, pointer

I am trying to create a library, where I have an array of pointers to functions in it. This array is used by other functions in the library. This is the code of the header file:

```
class Lib {
  public:
    static void call();
    static void (*caller[])();
  private:
};
```

This is the code of the .cpp-file:

```
#include "Lib.h"

void (*caller[2])();

void Lib::call() {
  caller[0]();
}
```

The sketch executing this is

```
#include <Lib.h>

void setup() {
  Lib::call();
}

void loop() {}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

> undefined reference to `Lib::caller'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Mehrere Bibliotheken wurden für "Lib.h" gefunden

Another weird thing is that the error about the multiple found libraries goes away if I take away the line

```
Lib::call();
```

However, if I put the same code directly into the sketch like so:

```
void (*caller[2])();

void call() {
  caller[0]();
}

void setup() {
  call();
}

void loop() {}
```

I get no error. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void (*caller[2])();
```

should be:

```
void (*Lib::caller[2])();
```

Since you are defining storage space for a static member variable you have to tell the compiler what class it's a static member of.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the part about the undefined reference. How does the problem with the multiple libraries originate from this though?

Comment: Probably because you do have two libraries named Lib.h somewhere?

Comment: (incidentally, I don't speak german, so had no clue what you were on about at first about multiple libraries...)

Comment: No, there is just one Lib.h file. The funny thing is, that, as I wrote, this error goes away when not calling the function in the sketch. And it also goes away with your solution. I was just wondering where it originated from.

Comment: Probably some bug in the IDE then...